# Why won't 3 of the women who have been pregnant for about 24 hours give birth?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I expanded my vault and added more living quarters and built storage. I have enough resources im fairly sure. The three women are working, but that shouldn't be a problem. I don't know if being armed with weapons would do anything, but they are armed. This is really confusing...

Comment: [Read this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3a1ahr/pregnant_dweller_for_more_than_24h/) and tell us if you moved the living quarters the babies were made in?

Comment: I did move the living quarters where the babies were made

Comment: Try moving it back to where it was or put a new one to the previous location. There's no workaround I've found for this yet.